# how to sum of two coloumn of different tables where customer_name is same in both in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

- order_tb
- delivery_tb

I want to sum of their two column i.e paid amount from table `order_tb` and `now_paid` from table `delivery_tb`.

In both table the `order_no` is same.

Can anyone suggest me how to do that.

Comment: Did you try join and mysql sum function ?

Comment: the query is working but issue is when I echo the output . It shows same sum with every record

Answer (score 1):

Based on what i understand, you are trying to get the sum of two columns from different table. If so, the following query might work, not tested.

```
  SELECT (order_tb.paid_amount + delivery_tb.now_paid) as total FROM order_tb 
JOIN delivery_tb ON(order_tb.order_no=delivery_tb.order_no)
```

Or what you want is sum of the column for each then the following query might work.

```
    SELECT SUM(order_tb.paid_amount) as paid_amount_total,
SUM(delivery_tb.now_paid) as now_paid_total FROM order_tb 
JOIN delivery_tb ON(order_tb.order_no=delivery_tb.order_no) 
group by delivery_tb.order_no
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8eda4/1)

Comment: thanks for response i will try

Comment: concept wise seems correct. need to test by Original Poster.

Comment: the query is working but issue is when I echo the output . It shows same sum with every record

Comment: Hi, I have edited the answer with SQL Fiddle. 
The query in that works properly.